# How to display logo and navbar in single row using angular?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

Can anyone help me to position the logo and navbar???

I am trying to put the "logo" inside the div(to the left side) and "navbar"  (to the right side) [like this in the image shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7coNV.png) but even though i tried many different properties my navbar is always occupy new line. Here is my code`

```css
.img-fluid {
  display: inline;
  max-width: 10% !important;
  margin-right: 17% !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: inline">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <img class="img-fluid" src={{imagePath}}>
    <br>
    <span><h6 style="color:white">Appointment System</h6></span>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline">
    <mat-toolbar class="toolbar-background">

      <a routerLink="customer" mat-button>Customer Form</a>
      <a routerLink="showAllCustomer" mat-button>Customer Details</a>

      <a (click)="logout()" mat-button>Logout</a>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a flex-box it will help you.

Comment: How about https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Use the flexbox since it's supported by about [97% of browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

Get used to flexbox and grid system. If you need to support obsolete IE you can use `float: left` to make them be side by side, but also you need to use `clear-fix`

There is a good explanation of your problem https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.img-fluid {
  max-width: 10% !important;
  margin-right: 17% !important;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <img class="img-fluid" src={{imagePath}}>
    <br>
    <span><h6 style="color:white">Appointment System</h6></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <mat-toolbar class="toolbar-background">

      <a routerLink="customer" mat-button>Customer Form</a>
      <a routerLink="showAllCustomer" mat-button>Customer Details</a>

      <a (click)="logout()" mat-button>Logout</a>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using `table`.

```css
.img-fluid {
  display: inline;
  max-width: 10% !important;
  margin-right: 17% !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- <div style="display: inline"> -->
  <table width="100%"><tr><td align="left">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <img class="img-fluid" src={{imagePath}}>
    <br>
    <span><h6 style="color:white">Appointment System</h6></span>
  <!-- </div> -->
  </td>
  <!-- <div style="display: inline"> -->
  <td align="right" valign="top">
    <mat-toolbar class="toolbar-background">

      <a routerLink="customer" mat-button>Customer Form</a>
      <a routerLink="showAllCustomer" mat-button>Customer Details</a>

      <a (click)="logout()" mat-button>Logout</a>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <!-- </div> -->
  </td></tr></table>
</div>
```